# hide/unhide menu links with password

Tags: javascript, html, menu

My website has a menu that hides/unhides basedon if a button is clicked or not. My goal, is to have a password box that will show the links in the menu if the password is correct, and keep them hidden if it is false. Security isn't the biggest item on my list just yet, I would just like to see it work. Also, I would like it to show the links without having to reload the whole page. Can this be done?

here is some of the html code for the menu:

```
 <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <x <font size="2"><font FACE="american typewriter">Title</font> </font></x>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Hello.</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Link1" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >hi.</a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="link2" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Math</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/341/ (the password is "CORRECT" for demo purposes

javascript:

```
function submit() {
    var pw = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    if(pw == 'CORRECT') {
        menu.className = "";            
    }
    else {
        menu.className = "hide";
    }
};
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="password"/>
<br/>
<button id="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul class="sidebar-nav hide" id="menu">
    <li class="sidebar-brand">
        Title
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#about" >Hello.</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Link1">hi.</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link2">Math</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.hide(
    display:none;
)
```